# Is java.util.Currency really a factory method pattern?

Tags: java

`java.util.currency` contains the following list:

```
private static HashMap<String, Currency> instances = new HashMap<String, Currency>(7);
```

Then the method `getInstance()` returns instances with the following criteria:

```
Currency instance = instances.get(currencyCode);
   if (instance != null) {
      return instance;
}
```

I was wondering what design pattern is it and why? Is it a factory method?

Comment: I'm not aware of a package named java.util.currency in the JDK !

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical implementation of the *Factory* method pattern where immutable instances are cached and reused ("memoized").

Answer (score 0):

The use of a factory method allows for a controlled creation and life cycle of objects, potentially from subclasses. As Marko Topolnik pointed out, it is not required for the method to return a new instance of `Currency`.

The trick provided in that code snippet is for `Currency` caching by their locale (or currency code). Since currencies of the same locale are just the same, there is no need to create multiple objects.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like a Singelton pattern, It's to make sure you only have one instance of the class